# Ajax post function not reaching controller using Kendo UI theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, controller, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I set a breakpoint at the function it is supposed to be calling, but while debugging, it never hits that point. I just upgraded to Kendo 2017.3.1026 from 2015 and replaced some scripts, but not the previous jquery.js files. Will it help to reference the jquery files contained within the Kendo package?

This is the error the Chrome console is giving me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
   at Object.success(Create:1990)
   at j (jquery.min.js:2)
   at Object.fireWith [asResolveWith] (jquery.min.js.2)
   at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

This is my code:

```
function resetDetailsAndDocuments(actualModule) {
    if (actualModule != null) {
        $("#KeepCurrentModuleId").val('true');
    } else {
        $("#KeepCurrentModuleId").val('false');
    }
    //Clear all documents uploadeds
    $(".k-delete").parent().click();
    var frm = $("#createForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "ReloadProjectDetailFromClient",
        data: frm,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#DivDetail").html(''); //replace our form content
            $("#DivDetail").html(data); //replace our form content

            //Set actual selection 
            if (actualModule != null) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#Project_ModId").data("kendoDropDownList").value(actualModule);
            }

            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set the data value of a jQuery object, the syntax is `.data('key', 'value')`

```
$("#Project_ModId").data("kendoDropDownList", actualModule);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. My issue is that from the Ajax post call, it does not reach the controller.